Getting "could not write profile file" when running Flutter on macOS
When I try to run my Flutter app on macOS, I get the following error:
error: could not write profile file: /Users/n/app/build/macos/Build/Products/Debug-prod/Sharezone.app/Contents/embedded.provisionprofile: fopen(/Users/n/app/build/macos/Build/Products/Debug-prod/Sharezone.app/Contents/embedded.provisionprofile, wb): Permission denied (13) (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
Error: Build process failed

Flutter version:
Flutter 3.24.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 4cf269e36d (5 days ago) • 2024-09-03 14:30:00 -0700
Engine • revision a6bd3f1de1
Tools • Dart 3.5.2 • DevTools 2.37.2


I fixed it by running the following commands:
sudo rm -rf build
flutter clean

